# The second attempt to input data after Clear button is clicked cannot generate the output(Java GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

Okay now after I made the correction here and there in the source code, the program works well.Somehow if I want to input for the next cutomer after I cleared the previous customer's data using button [Clear],when I clicked the [Receipt] button again the output on the Receipt panel was just displaying the toString statement I write outside the isSelected() blocks.what should I do to recover the error(because I think it is considered as an error for not being able to display the next output)

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import javax.swing.border.*;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class TestP extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{


//var for UPSR
private JTextField txtUh1, txtUh2, txtUh3, txtUh4, txtUh5,txtUt1, txtUt2,   txtUt3, txtUt4, txtUt5,txtTot;
private JLabel lblU1, lblU2, lblU3;
private JCheckBox cbUbm1,cbUbm2, cbUbi,cbUmath,cbUsc;


//var for PT3
 private JTextField txtPhbm,txtPhbi,txtPhm3,txtPhsc,txtPhag,txtPhsj,txtPhkh;
 private JTextField txtPtbm,txtPtbi,txtPtm3,txtPtsc,txtPtag,txtPtsj,txtPtkh;
 private JCheckBox cbPbm,cbPbi,cbPm3,cbPsc,cbPag,cbPsj,cbPkh;
 private JLabel lblP4,lblP5,lblP6;  // lblP1,lblP2,lblP3,lblP7,lblP8,lblP9
 private JTextField txtname,txtage,txtcontact;
 private JLabel lblname,lblage,lblcontact;

//var for SPM

private JTextField txtSprice, txtShbm, txtShbi, txtShsc, txtShag, txtShm3, txtShac, txtShpd, txtShaddm3, txtShcm, txtShbio, txtShfz, txtShsej, txtStbm, txtStbi, txtStsc, txtStag, txtStm3, txtStac, txtStpd, txtStaddm3, txtStcm, txtStbio, txtStfz, txtStsej;
private JLabel lblS1, lblS2, lblS3, lblS4;
private JCheckBox cbSbm, cbSbi, cbSsc, cbSag, cbSm3, cbSac, cbSpd, cbSaddm3, cbScm, cbSbio, cbSfz, cbSsej;
private JRadioButton rbUpsr,rbPt3,rbSpm;

private JButton btnReceipt = new JButton("RECEIPT");
private JButton btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR");
private JButton btnExit = new JButton("EXIT"); 

//button group for level
private ButtonGroup rbGroup = new ButtonGroup();

//Text Area for calculation
private JTextArea txtReceipt = new JTextArea("Super Tuition Center Sdn Bhd\t\t" + "\n"); 
//layout fixed size
private static final int width = 1350;
private static final int height = 730; 
Container pane = getContentPane();
Color c = new Color(217, 161, 63);
public TestP()
{
rbUpsr = new JRadioButton("UPSR");
rbPt3 = new JRadioButton("PT-3");
rbSpm = new JRadioButton("SPM");

   lblU1 = new JLabel("SUBJECT");
   lblU2 = new JLabel("HOUR/WEEK");
   lblU3 = new JLabel("TIME/WEEK");

   txtUh1 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUh2 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUh3 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUh4 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUh5 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUt1 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUt2 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUt3 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUt4 = new JTextField(10);
   txtUt5 = new JTextField(10);
   txtTot = new JTextField(10);

   cbUbm1 = new JCheckBox("BAHASA MELAYU PEMAHAMAN");
   cbUbm2 = new JCheckBox("BAHASA MELAYU PENULISAN");
   cbUbi = new JCheckBox("BAHASA INGGERIS");
   cbUmath = new JCheckBox("MATEMATIK");
   cbUsc = new JCheckBox("SAINS");


   txtPhbm=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhbi=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhm3=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhsc=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhag=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhsj=new JTextField(10);
    txtPhkh=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtbm=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtbi=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtm3=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtsc=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtag=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtsj=new JTextField(10);
    txtPtkh=new JTextField(10);

    lblP4=new JLabel("SUBJECT ");
    lblP5=new JLabel("HOUR/WEEK");
    lblP6=new JLabel("TIME/WEEK");

    cbPbm=new JCheckBox("BAHASA MELAYU :");
    cbPbi=new JCheckBox("BAHASA INGGERIS :");
    cbPm3=new JCheckBox("MATEMATIK :");
    cbPsc=new JCheckBox("SAINS :");
    cbPag=new JCheckBox("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM :");
    cbPsj=new JCheckBox("SEJARAH :");
    cbPkh=new JCheckBox("KEMAHIRAN HIDUP :");

     lblS1 = new JLabel("SUBJECT ");
    lblS2 = new JLabel("HOUR/WEEK");
    lblS3 = new JLabel("TIME/WEEK");


    txtShbm = new JTextField(10);
    txtShbi = new JTextField(10);
    txtShsc = new JTextField(10);
    txtShag = new JTextField(10);
    txtShm3 = new JTextField(10);
    txtShac = new JTextField(10);
    txtShpd = new JTextField(10);
    txtShaddm3 = new JTextField(10);
    txtShcm = new JTextField(10);
    txtShbio = new JTextField(10);
    txtShfz = new JTextField(10);
    txtShsej = new JTextField(10);
    txtSprice = new JTextField(10);
    txtStbm = new JTextField(10);
    txtStbi = new JTextField(10);
    txtStsc = new JTextField(10);
    txtStag = new JTextField(10);
    txtStm3 = new JTextField(10);
    txtStac = new JTextField(10);
    txtStpd = new JTextField(10);
    txtStaddm3 = new JTextField(10);
    txtStcm = new JTextField(10);
    txtStbio = new JTextField(10);
    txtStfz = new JTextField(10);
    txtStsej = new JTextField(10);

    lblname=new JLabel("NAME : ");
    lblage=new JLabel("AGE : ");
    lblcontact=new JLabel("CONTACT NO : ");
    txtname=new JTextField(30);
    txtage=new JTextField(5);
    txtcontact=new JTextField(15);

    cbSbm = new JCheckBox("BAHASA MELAYU");
    cbSbi = new JCheckBox("BAHASA INGGERIS");
    cbSsc = new JCheckBox("SAINS");
    cbSag = new JCheckBox("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM");
    cbSm3 = new JCheckBox("MATEMATIK");
    cbSac = new JCheckBox("AKAUN");
    cbSpd = new JCheckBox("PERDAGANGAN");
    cbSaddm3 = new JCheckBox("MATEMATIK TAMBAHAN");
    cbScm = new JCheckBox("KIMIA");
    cbSbio = new JCheckBox("BIOLOGI");
    cbSfz = new JCheckBox("FIZIK");
    cbSsej = new JCheckBox("SEJARAH");





   //setting for main panel
   setTitle("Super Tuition");
   setSize(width, height);

   setVisible(true);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
   p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,3));
   p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("UPSR"));
   p1.setBackground(Color.pink);
   //p1.setSize(400,400);
   p1.add(lblU1);
   lblU1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   p1.add(lblU2);
   lblU2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   p1.add(lblU3);
   lblU3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

   p1.add(cbUbm1);
   cbUbm1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p1.add(txtUh1);
   p1.add(txtUt1);

   p1.add(cbUbm2);
   cbUbm2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p1.add(txtUh2);
   p1.add(txtUt2);

   p1.add(cbUbi);
   cbUbi.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p1.add(txtUh3);
   p1.add(txtUt3);

   p1.add(cbUmath);
   cbUmath.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p1.add(txtUh4);
   p1.add(txtUt4);

   p1.add(cbUsc);
   cbUsc.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p1.add(txtUh5);
   p1.add(txtUt5);


   //add components for PT-3
   JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
   p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,3));
   p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("PT-3"));
   p2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
   p2.setSize(400,400);

   p2.add(lblP4);
   lblP4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   p2.add(lblP5);
   p2.add(lblP6);

   p2.add(cbPbm);
   cbPbm.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhbm);
   p2.add(txtPtbm);

   p2.add(cbPbi);
   cbPbi.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhbi);
   p2.add(txtPtbi);

   p2.add(cbPm3);
   cbPm3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhm3);
   p2.add(txtPtm3);

   p2.add(cbPsc);
   cbPsc.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhsc);
   p2.add(txtPtsc);

   p2.add(cbPag);
   cbPag.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhag);
   p2.add(txtPtag);

   p2.add(cbPsj);
   cbPsj.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhsj);
   p2.add(txtPtsj);

   p2.add(cbPkh);
   cbPkh.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p2.add(txtPhkh);
   p2.add(txtPtkh);


   //add components for SPM 
   JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
   p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,3));
   p3.setBorder(new TitledBorder("SPM"));
   p3.setBackground(Color.PINK);


   p3.add(lblS1);
   lblS1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   p3.add(lblS2);
   lblS1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
   p3.add(lblS3);
   lblS1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

   p3.add(cbSbm);
   cbSbm.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShbm);
   p3.add(txtStbm);

   p3.add(cbSbi);
   cbSbi.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShbi);
   p3.add(txtStbi);

   p3.add(cbSsej);
   cbSsej.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShsej);
   p3.add(txtStsej);

   p3.add(cbSag);
   cbSag.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShag);
   p3.add(txtStag);

   p3.add(cbSm3);
   cbSm3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShm3);
   p3.add(txtStm3);

   p3.add(cbSaddm3);
   cbSaddm3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShaddm3);
   p3.add(txtStaddm3);

   p3.add(cbSsc);
   cbSsc.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShsc);
   p3.add(txtStsc);

   p3.add(cbScm);
   cbScm.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShcm);
   p3.add(txtStcm);

   p3.add(cbSfz);
   cbSfz.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShfz);
   p3.add(txtStfz);

   p3.add(cbSbio);
   cbSbio.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShbio);
   p3.add(txtStbio);

   p3.add(cbSac);
   cbSac.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShac);
   p3.add(txtStac);

   p3.add(cbSpd);
   cbSpd.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   p3.add(txtShpd);
   p3.add(txtStpd);


   //add components for Button Panel
   JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
   p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,3));
   p4.setBorder(new TitledBorder("RECEIPT"));
   p4.setBackground(Color.red);




   //add components for Main panel

   JPanel p5 = new JPanel();

    setBackground(Color.orange);

   p5.add(lblname);

   p5.add(txtname);

   p5.add(lblage);

   p5.add(txtage);

   p5.add(lblcontact);

   p5.add(txtcontact);

   p5.add(btnReceipt);

   btnReceipt.addActionListener(this);

   p5.add(btnClear);

   btnClear.addActionListener(this);

   p5.add(btnExit);

   btnExit.addActionListener(this);

   p5.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
   rbGroup.add(rbUpsr);
   p5.add(rbUpsr);
   rbUpsr.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
   rbUpsr.addActionListener(this);

   rbGroup.add(rbPt3);
   p5.add(rbPt3);
   rbPt3.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
   rbPt3.addActionListener(this);

   rbGroup.add(rbSpm);
   p5.add(rbSpm);
   rbSpm.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
   rbSpm.addActionListener(this);



   JPanel receipt = new JPanel();

   receipt.setBorder( new TitledBorder("TOTAL PAYMENT RECEIPT"));
   receipt.setBackground(Color.pink);
   receipt.add(txtReceipt); 

   txtReceipt.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 13));
   //end panel receipt 

   pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   pane.add(p1,"South");
   pane.add(p2,"Center");
   pane.add(p3,"West");
   pane.add(p5,"North");
   pane.add(receipt,"East"); // end outermost panel
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {


    if (event.getSource() == btnReceipt)
    {
        double totD=0.0,totalS=0.0,totalU=0.0,totalP=0.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double totP=0.0;
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\t\tWELCOME TO SUPER TUITION CENTER SDN BHD" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("CUSTOMER'S NAME:" +txtname.getText()+"\n");
        txtReceipt.append("AGE\t              :" +txtage.getText()+"\n");
        txtReceipt.append("CONTACT NO             :" +txtcontact.getText()+"\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        txtReceipt.append("SUBJECTS :         " + "\t\t PRICE"+ "\tHOUR"+ "\tTIME" + "\tTOTAL" + "\n");
        txtReceipt.append("\n");
        if(rbUpsr.isSelected()){
       int countU=0;
       double totbm1=0.0,totbm2=0.0,totbi=0.0,totmath=0.0,totsc=0.0;

        if (cbUbm1.isSelected())
        {
            int hrbm1 = Integer.parseInt(txtUh1.getText());
            int tmbm1 = Integer.parseInt(txtUt1.getText());
            totbm1=20*hrbm1*tmbm1;
            countU++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU PEMAHAMAN " + "\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbm1 + "\t"+tmbm1+"\t"+ df.format( totbm1) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if (cbUbm2.isSelected())
        {
            int hrbm2 = Integer.parseInt(txtUh2.getText());
            int tmbm2 = Integer.parseInt(txtUt2.getText());
            totbm2=20*hrbm2*tmbm2;
            countU++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU PENULISAN " + "\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbm2 + "\t" +tmbm2+"\t"+ df.format( totbm2) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if (cbUbi.isSelected())
        {
            int hrbi = Integer.parseInt(txtUh3.getText());
            int tmbi = Integer.parseInt(txtUt3.getText());
            totbi=20*hrbi*tmbi;
            countU++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS          " + "\t\tRM 20.00" + "\t" + hrbi + "\t" +tmbi+"\t"+ df.format( totbi) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if (cbUmath.isSelected())
        {
            int hrmath = Integer.parseInt(txtUh4.getText());
            int tmmath= Integer.parseInt(txtUt4.getText());
            totmath=20*hrmath*tmmath;
            countU++;
            txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK                " + "\t\tRM 20.00" +"\t"+ hrmath + "\t" +tmmath+"\t"+ df.format( totmath) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if (cbUsc.isSelected())
        {
            int hrsc = Integer.parseInt(txtUh5.getText());
            int tmsc = Integer.parseInt(txtUt5.getText());
            totsc=20*hrsc*tmsc;
            txtReceipt.append("SAINS                    " + "\t\tRM 20.00" +"\t" + hrsc + "\t" +tmsc+"\t"+ df.format( totsc) + "\n"); // set to text area
            countU++;
        }
        totalU=totbm1+totbm2+totbi+totmath+totsc;
        if(countU>5){
            totD=totalU*0.1;
           totP=totalU-totD;
        }
        else{
            totP=totalU;
        }
        txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" +totalU+"0" + "\n");
    }

      if(rbPt3.isSelected()){

     double pbm=0.0,pbi=0.0,pm3=0.0,psc=0.0,pag=0.0,psj=0.0,pkh=0.0;

     int countP=0;

         if(cbPbm.isSelected())
        {   int textPhbm=Integer.parseInt(txtPhbm.getText());
            int textPtbm=Integer.parseInt(txtPtbm.getText());
            pbm=35*textPhbm*textPtbm;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU            " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhbm + "\t  " +textPtbm+ "\t  "+df.format(pbm) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPbi.isSelected())
        {   int textPhbi=Integer.parseInt(txtPhbi.getText());
            int textPtbi=Integer.parseInt(txtPtbi.getText());
            pbi=35*textPhbi*textPtbi;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS          " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhbi + "\t  " +textPtbi+"\t  "+ df.format(pbi) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPm3.isSelected())
        {   int textPhm3=Integer.parseInt(txtPhm3.getText());
            int textPtm3=Integer.parseInt(txtPtm3.getText());
            pm3=35*textPhm3*textPtm3;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK                " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhm3 + "\t  " +textPtm3+"\t  "+ df.format(pm3) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPsc.isSelected())
        {   int textPhsc=Integer.parseInt(txtPhsc.getText());
            int textPtsc=Integer.parseInt(txtPtsc.getText());
            psc=35*textPhsc*textPtsc;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("SAINS                    " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhsc + "\t  " +textPtsc+ "\t  "+ df.format(psc) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPag.isSelected())
        {   int textPhag=Integer.parseInt(txtPhag.getText());
            int textPtag=Integer.parseInt(txtPtag.getText());
            pag=35*textPhag*textPtag;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM         " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhag + "\t  " +textPtag+ "\t  "+ df.format(pag) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPsj.isSelected())
        {   int textPhsj=Integer.parseInt(txtPhsj.getText());
            int textPtsj=Integer.parseInt(txtPtsj.getText());
            psj=35*textPhsj*textPtsj;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("SEJARAH                  " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhsj + "\t  " +textPtsj+ "\t  "+ df.format(psj) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }
        if(cbPkh.isSelected())
        {   int textPhkh=Integer.parseInt(txtPhkh.getText());
            int textPtkh=Integer.parseInt(txtPtkh.getText());
            pkh=35*textPhkh*textPtkh;
            countP++;
            txtReceipt.append("KEMAHIRAN HIDUP          " + "\t\tRM 35.00" + "\t  " + textPhkh + "\t  " +textPtkh+ "\t  "+ df.format(pkh) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        totalP=pbm+pbi+pm3+psc+pag+psj+pkh;

        if(countP>=6)
        {
            totD=totalP*0.1;
            totP=totalP-totD;
        }
        else{
            totP=totalP;
        }
        txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" +totalP +"0"+ "\n");

      }

    if(rbSpm.isSelected()){
         double bm=0.0, bi=0.0, ag=0.0, sej=0.0, m3=0.0, addm3=0.0, sc=0.0, cm=0.0, bio=0.0, fz=0.0, ac=0.0, pd=0.0; 
        int countS = 0;

        if(cbSbm.isSelected())
        {
            int hbm = Integer.parseInt(txtShbm.getText());
            int tbm = Integer.parseInt(txtStbm.getText());
            bm = 50*hbm*tbm;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA MELAYU         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbm + "\t   " +tbm+ "\t   "+ df.format(bm) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSbi.isSelected())
        {
            int hbi = Integer.parseInt(txtShbi.getText());
            int tbi = Integer.parseInt(txtStbi.getText());
            bi = 50*hbi*tbi;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("BAHASA INGGERIS         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbi + "\t   " +tbi+"\t   "+ df.format(bi) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSag.isSelected())
        {
            int hag = Integer.parseInt(txtShag.getText());
            int tag = Integer.parseInt(txtStag.getText());
            ag = 50*hag*tag;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("PENDIDIKAN ISLAM         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hag + "\t   " +tag+"\t   "+ df.format(ag) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSsej.isSelected())
        {
            int hsej = Integer.parseInt(txtShsej.getText());
            int tsej = Integer.parseInt(txtStsej.getText());
            sej = 50*hsej*tsej;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("SEJARAH         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hsej + "\t   " +tsej+"\t   "+ df.format(sej) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSm3.isSelected())
        {
            int hm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtShm3.getText());
            int tm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtStm3.getText());
            m3 = 50*hm3*tm3;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK         " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hm3 + "\t   " +tm3+"\t   "+ df.format(m3) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSaddm3.isSelected())
        {
            int haddm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtShaddm3.getText());
            int taddm3 = Integer.parseInt(txtStaddm3.getText());
            addm3 = 50*haddm3*taddm3;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("MATEMATIK TAMBAHAN " + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + haddm3 + "\t   " +taddm3+"\t   "+ df.format(addm3) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSsc.isSelected())
        {
            int hsc = Integer.parseInt(txtShsc.getText());
            int tsc = Integer.parseInt(txtStsc.getText());
            sc = 50*hsc*tsc;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("SAINS         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hsc + "\t   " +tsc+ "\t   "+ df.format(sc) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbScm.isSelected())
        {
            int hcm = Integer.parseInt(txtShcm.getText());
            int tcm = Integer.parseInt(txtStcm.getText());
            cm = 50*hcm*tcm;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("KIMIA         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hcm + "\t   " +tcm+ "\t   "+ df.format( cm) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSbio.isSelected())
        {
            int hbio = Integer.parseInt(txtShbio.getText());
            int tbio = Integer.parseInt(txtStbio.getText());
            bio = 50*hbio*tbio;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("BIOLOGI" + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hbio + "\t   " +tbio+ "\t   "+ df.format( bio) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSfz.isSelected())
        {
            int hfz = Integer.parseInt(txtShfz.getText());
            int tfz = Integer.parseInt(txtStfz.getText());
            fz = 50*hfz*tfz;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("FIZIK         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hfz + "\t   " +tfz+ "\t   "+ df.format( fz) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSac.isSelected())
        {
            int hac = Integer.parseInt(txtShac.getText());
            int tac = Integer.parseInt(txtStac.getText());
            ac = 50*hac*tac;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("AKAUN         " + "\t\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hac + "\t   " +tac+ "\t   "+ df.format(ac) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        if(cbSpd.isSelected())
        {
            int hpd = Integer.parseInt(txtShpd.getText());
            int tpd = Integer.parseInt(txtStpd.getText());
            pd = 50*hpd*tpd;
            countS++;
            txtReceipt.append("PERDAGANGAN" + "\t\tRM 50.00" + "\t   " + hpd + "\t   " +tpd+ "\t   "+ df.format( pd) + "\n"); // set to text area
        }

        totalS = bm + bi + ag + sej + m3 + addm3 + sc + cm + fz + ac + pd;

        if(countS >= 6)
        {
            totD=totalS*0.1;
            totP=totalS-totD;
        }
        else{
            totP=totalS;
        }
        txtReceipt.append("TOTAL FEES : " + "\t\t" + "RM" +totP+"0"+ "\n");
    }



            txtReceipt.append("\n");

            txtReceipt.append("TOTAL DISCOUNT : " + "\t\t" + "RM " +totD +"0"+ "\n");
            txtReceipt.append("TOTAL PAYMENT PER MONTH : " + "\t" + "RM" +(totP*4)+"0" + "\n");//txtTot.getText()
            txtReceipt.append("\n");
            txtReceipt.append("\t  THANK YOU FOR CHOOSING SUPER TUITION SDN BHD" + "\n");

            txtReceipt.append("\n"); // set to text area
        }
    if (event.getSource() == btnClear)
    {
        cbUbm1.setSelected(false);
        cbUbm2.setSelected(false);
        cbUbi.setSelected(false);
        cbUmath.setSelected(false);
        cbUsc.setSelected(false);

        txtUh1.setText(" ");
        txtUh2.setText(" ");
        txtUh3.setText(" ");
        txtUh4.setText(" ");
        txtUh5.setText(" ");

        txtUt1.setText(" ");
        txtUt2.setText(" ");
        txtUt3.setText(" ");
        txtUt4.setText(" ");
        txtUt5.setText(" ");

    txtPhbm.setText(" ");
    txtPhbi.setText(" ");
    txtPhm3.setText(" ");
    txtPhsc.setText(" ");
    txtPhag.setText(" ");
    txtPhsj.setText(" ");
    txtPhkh.setText(" ");
    txtPtbm.setText(" ");
    txtPtbi.setText(" ");
    txtPtm3.setText(" ");
    txtPtsc.setText(" ");
    txtPtag.setText(" ");
    txtPtsj.setText(" ");
    txtPtkh.setText(" ");


    cbPbm.setSelected(false);
    cbPbi.setSelected(false);
    cbPm3.setSelected(false);
    cbPsc.setSelected(false);
    cbPag.setSelected(false);
    cbPsj.setSelected(false);
    cbPkh.setSelected(false);




    txtShbm.setText(" ");
    txtShbi.setText(" ");
    txtShsc.setText(" ");
    txtShag.setText(" ");
    txtShm3.setText(" ");
    txtShac.setText(" ");
    txtShpd.setText(" ");
    txtShaddm3.setText(" ");
    txtShcm.setText(" ");
    txtShbio.setText(" ");
    txtShfz.setText(" ");
    txtShsej.setText(" ");

    txtStbm.setText(" ");
    txtStbi.setText(" ");
    txtStsc.setText(" ");
    txtStag.setText(" ");
    txtStm3.setText(" ");
    txtStac.setText(" ");
    txtStpd.setText(" ");
    txtStaddm3.setText(" ");
    txtStcm.setText(" ");
    txtStbio.setText(" ");
    txtStfz.setText(" ");
    txtStsej.setText(" ");

    cbSbm.setSelected(false);
    cbSbi.setSelected(false);
    cbSsc.setSelected(false);
    cbSag.setSelected(false);
    cbSm3.setSelected(false);
    cbSac.setSelected(false);
    cbSpd.setSelected(false);
    cbSaddm3.setSelected(false);
    cbScm.setSelected(false);
    cbSbio.setSelected(false);
    cbSfz.setSelected(false);
    cbSsej.setSelected(false);
    txtname.setText(" ");
    txtage.setText(" ");
    txtcontact.setText(" ");

        rbUpsr.setSelected(false);
        rbPt3.setSelected(false);
        rbSpm.setSelected(false);
        txtReceipt.setText("\t  WELCOME TO SUPER TUITION SDN BHD\t\t" + "\n"); //clearing all data that are available
    }    


    if (event.getSource() == btnExit)
    {
        System.exit(0); //exit the program
    }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    TestP t = new TestP(); //main application
    t.setVisible(true);
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
  }
```

Comment: What "errors" are you seeing?

Comment: You should maybe narrow the code and localize the problem please.

Comment: I agree with @YassinHajaj: you will want to refactor this code, as right now you have one huge class that tries to do every thing, making for confusing and complex code. Better to carve out classes, each with its own single responsibility, each individually testable and debuggable.

Comment: javax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@5e70cf11,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],c

Comment: above is the error.if you could compile and run the program i guess you can see the error.it has no syntax error when i compile it.and im sorry im just totally a newbie in java GUI too.so i just had learnt to code it in one class

Comment: and it happens when i clicked the RECEIPT button

Comment: @user5510709 It is better to use the edit option of the post to add more information on the question.

Comment: You're seeing the `toString()` returned from on JTextField. Never try to print out a text field, only its text, which you get by calling `toString()` on it. Also you need to learn and use layout managers.

Comment: @YassinHajaj i tried before to edit but it will just exceed the characters limit

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels er,im not quite clear on that toString in this topic.but still,TQ anyway :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh myy..finally I get to display the output.thanks a lot :DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the toString() returned from on JTextField. Never try to print out a text field, only its text, which you get by calling toString() on it.

Here:

```
txtReceipt.append("TOTAL PAYMENT" + "\t\t\t" + "    RM" + txtTot + "\n");
```

You're printing out a JTextField, txtTot, and not the text it contains. Don't do this. Rather do:

```
txtReceipt.append("TOTAL PAYMENT" + "\t\t\t" + "    RM" + txtTot.getText() + "\n");
```

And similarly for all other JTextFields that you might be trying to print.

Also

- While null layouts and setBounds() might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- You appear to have one huge "God" class, a class that tries to do everything, and this is not good since this makes for confusing and complex code. Better to carve out multiple smaller classes, each with its own single responsibility, each individually testable and debuggable.

Comment: Hi.since im using JPanel in this program how do I add Scrollpane for the Receipt area?do I need to add it in main or class TestP? and my program can only display output for the first time.and second customer info cannot be displayed after I clicked the Clear button.How to correct that?

Comment: @user5510709: looks like you've got new questions, and each should be asked separately within its own question. As for JScrollPane, the tutorials will show you how to use them, and I suggest that you check this out before asking your question. Also, do try to refactor that huge class into smaller classes before moving forward as it will make debugging, enhancing and changing **much** easier for both you and us.

Comment: I'm sorry for not refactoring this class into the smaller ones as you guys had told me so before.I'm running out of time now so I just can focus on this one first.After all the requirements of the program is already fulfilled,now I'm just focusing to improve the program for the output as I will need to submit this program in this week too.maybe after this week I can study this GUI thoroughly before asking you guys  dummy questions like these.I'm still in the process of learning basic Java though.

Comment: @user5510709: Please don't misunderstand: my comment above was not meant to criticize you or your efforts, but were suggestions to try to help move you forward. Also the refactoring suggestion can help immediately on a practical basis. For example if after reading the JScrollPane tutorial you're still stuck on how to use it, and you decide to ask this question here, it's an easy one to answer usually as it usually involves just a few lines of code, but to fully understand your current code, ...

Comment: @user5510709 (continued) .... and to be able to compile and run it, would require the volunteer trying to help you to go through almost 800 lines of code, most of it completely unrelated to the problem at hand. So you see our predicament. Regardless, your original question has been answered, so again if you have further problems, I reiterate my suggestions to go through the [JScrollPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) (please check out the link) or if still stuck, ask a new question.

Comment: No I appreciate your advice but I just want you to know why I didnt apply your suggestion before in my codes :) Oh yes,bout the accept button I only know bout it after you have mentioned it to me just now.I'm still not getting used to the basic functions of this website and how it works bout those reputations,answers and so on.thank you by the way for telling me that

Comment: oh yes about the whole code I've posted here,it was because from what I read on other people's problem in here, I thought  the other people who gave them solutions will require the whole code to know where is the problem/error.my bad again.now I know

Comment: @user5510709: it's always a difficult decision on what code to post and what to leave out. If possible, you will want to post the **smallest** possible program that compiles and runs, and shows your problem. When you have a huge class, this is hard to create, but if you have smaller classes, then it's much easier to create and post this [mcve].